# Get all descendant components of a parent, even if there are rendered via router-outlet

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a main component that need to check if it contains a certain type of component inside all currently rendered components:

In app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In app.component.ts:

```
@ViewChildren(ComponentToFind) query: QueryList<ComponentToFind>;
```

However, even if I navigate to a page containing a component of type ComponentToFind, nothing is returned inside the _results property of QueryList.

So is there a possibility to retrieve all components with a certain type inside the tree of visible components, even if there are rendered via router-outlet ?

Comment: Not with angular board Utils. But you could use the browsers `document.getElementsByTagName()` for that. Would be pretty bad performance-wise though, as you'd need to rerun that during each change detection. What exactly do you want to accomplish by doing that? Can't see a problem where you want to query deep honestly...

Comment: I want to implement a bottom bar that can have custom actions, depending of the currently displayed component of type ComponentToFind.

Comment: In that case you could add a service that has a `register()` and `unregister()` method, register your ComponentToFind in its `ngOnInit` hook and unregister it in its `ngOnDestroy` hook. Inject that service in your bottom bar and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

first check that whether you declared child components in parent module.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
   import {ChildComponent} from './child.component';

   @NgModule({
   declarations: [ChildComponent],
   imports: [],
    providers: [],
       bootstrap: [ParentComponent]
   })
   export class ParentModule {}
```

Comment: That's not the problem. `@ViewChildren` is only able to find children that are defined in the view of the component (hence the name `ViewChildren`). It cannot find anything declared in the view of its children.